# Controller.File Method (Byte[], String) returns blank on localhost

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf, msdn

I am trying to generate PDF using Controller.File Method (Byte[], String) of System.Web.Mvc Namespace ... But its returning blank page .. following is my function ..

```
public override ActionResult GeneratePDF()
{
    bool bDisplayInline = true;
    bool.TryParse((string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DisplayPDFInline"], out bDisplayInline);

    string sDownloadFileName = DownloadFileName();


    String sHtmlPage = this.RenderView("Pdf", ViewModel);

    PDFHTML htmlModel = new PDFHTML();
    htmlModel.html = sHtmlPage;

    htmlModel.header = this.RenderView("PDF_Header", buildPDFHeaderModel(RunDate));
    htmlModel.footer = Consts.PDF_Footer;
    var absoluteUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["localUrl"] + Request.FilePath;
    byte[] pdfDoc = GeneratePDFHelper.BuildPDF(HttpContext.ApplicationInstance.Response, absoluteUri, htmlModel, sDownloadFileName, bDisplayInline);

    return File(pdfDoc, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf);
}
```

can anyone tell me whats an issue why its returning blank page ...

**Note:** **Byte array is not empty** ..

Comment: Have you compared the bytes in `pdfDoc` with the data returned by ASP.NET Core? (Save the "blank" document for comparison.)

Comment: sorry I am new at this can you please tell me how to do that ?

Comment: And it is working fine on production but on local it is returning blank page

Comment: Not sure what you're asking how to do - save the file, or compare the bytes?

Comment: compare the bytes

Comment: Well you'd look in the debugger at what the bytes look like (at least the length and maybe copy the first 16 bytes onto the clipboard) then open the file in a binary file editor...

Comment: `System.Exception: Conversion error: Navigation timeout.
   at SelectPdf.HtmlToImage.` am getting this exception thats y m getting blank url do you knw why it is coming ? @JonSkeet

Comment: If you're getting an exception, I'd expect the web browser to show an error rather than just serve a blank page. It doesn't help that we have no idea what `SelectPdf.HtmlToImage` is. Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/

Comment: ok and `SelectPdf.HtmlToImage` is [link](https://selectpdf.com/html-to-pdf/docs/html/M_SelectPdf_HtmlToPdf_ConvertHtmlString_1.htm)

Comment: But we've no idea where that's being called from. I very much doubt that's it during the `File(...)` call, which means that the `GeneratePDFHelper.BuildPDF` method must have succeeded if you're able to see "byte array is not empty". It's really, really unclear what's going on in your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146250/discussion-between-zain-abbas-and-jon-skeet).